# Cucmber this.AfterFeatures is hooked Before features started to run

Tags: javascript, protractor, cucumber

No Matter what I tried to do `this.AfterFeatures` hook keep calling before all features are even start running. Tried to find a solution on line and didn't seem to find a reason why is this happening?

I am using protractor and cucumber (custome) as a framework:

```
var myAfterHooks = function () { 
    this.AfterFeatures(function (event, callback) {
        console.log('AfterFeatures');
        callback();
    });
};

module.exports = myAfterHooks;
```

tried also using `registerHandler('AfterFeatures', function (event, callback) {`.

Which didn't solve it at all.